# Stroke width transform alternative

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

I've thought about using the following method to determine stroke width:

- compute the distance of a pixel from the edge of the shape (bwdist in Matlab)
- compute the skeleton of the blob using Lam-Lee's skeletonization algorithm (bwmorph('thin',inf) in Matlab)
- measure the stroke width on the distance transformed image where the skeleton passes.

The skeleton is supposed to pass through the local maxima of the distance transform, If I'm not mistaken.

This seems more straightforward to me than "flood-filling" the shape according to the gradients of the distance transform, and it also gives equal weight to thin strokes and to wide strokes.

Is this a good approach, or did I make a mistake in my reasoning? 
Why doesn't anyone use this approach?